# Miniature DPDT Hf Rf Switch

Tags: switch

I am in need of a miniature or sub-miniature DPDT push button panel mounted switch to use as an HF Rf by-pass switch in a 10watt digital transmitter. Basic spec: >3amps, 250VAC, <0.1 db loss at 30Mhz.

If my spec is off, please correct it. I have looked all over and can not find the switch. Part number, mfg, link to spec sheet, all appreciated.

Comment: Hi Whs, welcome (again) to Hardware Recommendations. You may want to try electronics.stackexchange.com; we can try to help you here, but we aren't typically very strong with individual electronics components here.

Comment: Hello, JMY1000; I have tried several times to lnk to "electronics.stackexchange.com". Keeps bringing me back to EEstack. Please provide a link to the site you feel is more appropriate. Thank you

Comment: Hi Whs, the EE stack is the location I'd recommend for *this* question specifically. It's still appropriate for this site, but I doubt you'll get much help here just because of what we tend to focus on.